# pod install が出来ない

Tags: swift, cocoapods

CocoaPodsの導入について、質問させてください。

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapos  
$ pod setup
```

ここまではうまくいきました。

希望のディレクトリに移動し、

```
$ pod init
```

Podfileが作られる。

必要事項をPodfile書き込み、保存。

`pod install`を実行したところ、下記のようなエラーが出ました。
バージョンのアップデートなども行ってみたのですが、何が悪いのかわからず、教えてもらえればと思います。

````
Updating local specs repositories

CocoaPods 1.0.0.beta.5 is available.
To update use: `gem install cocoapods --pre`
[!] This is a test version we'd love you to try.

For more information see http://blog.cocoapods.org
and the CHANGELOG for this version http://git.io/BaH8pQ.

Analyzing dependencies

――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

### Command

```
/usr/local/bin/pod install
```

### Report

* What did you do?

* What did you expect to happen?

* What happened instead?


### Stack  
```
   CocoaPods : 0.39.0  
        Ruby : ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin15]  
    RubyGems : 2.6.1  
        Host : Mac OS X 10.11.3 (15D21)  
       Xcode : 7.2.1 (7C1002)  
         Git : git version 2.5.4 (Apple Git-61)  
Ruby lib dir : /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.0/lib  
Repositories : master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ b0939fb1eea16e3f6e6848c2d924d997d0f66a09  
```
### Plugins

```
cocoapods-plugins : 0.4.2
cocoapods-search  : 0.1.0
cocoapods-stats   : 0.6.2
cocoapods-trunk   : 0.6.4
cocoapods-try     : 0.5.1
```

### Podfile

```ruby
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

target 'Chapter6' do
pod 'RealmSwift'
pod 'AFNetworking'
end
```

### Error

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `to_ary' for #<Pod::Specification name="AFNetworking">
Did you mean?  to_query
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver/lazy_specification.rb:14:in `method_missing'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:64:in `flatten'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:64:in `block in resolve'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:63:in `tap'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:63:in `resolve'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:539:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:59:in `section'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:537:in `resolve_dependencies'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:70:in `analyze'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:213:in `analyze'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:136:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:59:in `section'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:135:in `resolve_dependencies'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:105:in `install!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command/project.rb:71:in `run_install_with_update'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command/project.rb:101:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-0.9.1/lib/claide/command.rb:312:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:47:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/bin/pod:44:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
```

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CocoaPods 0.39はRuby 2.3には対応していません。Rubyのバージョンを2.2.xに下げるか、まだβ版ですが、CocoaPodsのバージョンを1.0 betaに上げてください。

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4891

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
CococaPodsのバージョンを1.0.0.beta.2にすることで無事に出来ました。